# How to pass object to an ArrayList in different Controllers(java FX)

Tags: javafx, fxml

In JAVA FX have an application with one window that creates a customer with insurances and another window with a tableView where I want to show information about the customers. In the tableView window, I also have an ArrayList. When I close the registration window the application sends the customer object to the ArrayList. This works fine,  but when I do register another customers insurance, the ArrayList seems to go empty before taking in the new object. Summarized it seems that my ArrayList only will hold one object at a time.

```
//In the registration controller, this code is called when I close the window and pass the customer object
```

```
    FXMLDocumentController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.initForsikredeKunder(passedCustomer);
```

//---------- In the view tableclass
    private ArrayList = null;

public void initForsikredeKunder (Kunde customer) {
    if(kundeListe == null) {
        kundeListe = new ArrayList<Kunde>();
    }
    this.kundeListe.add(customer);
}

Why does the ArrayList just hold one customer? seems to me that this code only makes one ArrayList, and then just should just add customers
as they get passed to the method. However, that is not happening

Answer (score 0):

You do appear to have a typo, so I assume private ArrayList = null is really:

```
private ArrayList kundeListe = null;
```

The code looks fine (I'm guessing at some of the context), although there are some things I would improve. It only creates a new list when "kundeListe" is null - so the list isn't getting wiped out. So if you call initForsikredeKunder() a second time, all it'll do is add a second "customer".

Basically, you can just call initForsikredeKunder() repeatedly and it'll work fine.

I would rename initForsikredeKunder to say "add" instead of init. It's really an add operation which also handles lazy initialization of a backing list.

Going further, you could do this:

```
private List<Kunde> kundeListe = new ArrayList<>();
```

and remove the lazy init:

```
public void addKunder (Kunde customer) {
    kundeListe.add(customer);
}
```

Note: I'm not 100% I understood your narrative above, so I could be misunderstanding what's going on. If this "dialog/window" only ever works with a single customer, you don't even need to use the List!

**Edits after additional info provided:**

Based on your code it looks like the original dialog isn't being re-used. The "new FXMLLoader()" part is fine.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
Parent tableViewParent = loader.load();
Scene tableViewScene = new Scene(tableViewParent); //Access the controller and call the method
FXMLDocumentController controller = loader.getController();
controller.initForsikredeKunder(valgtKunde); // having trouble finding what it should say instead of = new FXMLLoader();
```

So probably the easiest thing to do, if your dialog requires multiple customers, is to just pass in more than one with the initForsikredKunder() call.

How about this?

```
public void initForsikredeKunder (Kunde... customer) {
    if(kundeListe == null) {
        kundeListe = new ArrayList<Kunde>();
    }
    for (Kunde cust : customer) {
        this.kundeListe.add(cust);
    }
}
```

Then change the initForsikredeKunder() call to this:

```
controller.initForsikredeKunder(valgtKunde1, valgtKunde2, valgtKunde3);//Add as many as you need
```

If you already have a long list of "valgtKunde":

```
public void initForsikredeKunder (List<Kunde> customers) {
    if(kundeListe == null) {
        kundeListe = new ArrayList<Kunde>();
    }
    this.kundeListe.addAll(customers);
}
```

... and pass the list to initForsikredeKunder(customerList);

This is the kind of thing where the larger context matters, unfortunately it's hard to convey all of that here I guess, so there could be some adjustments required depending on broader context. (i.e. what data you're starting with and what the dialog functionality supports)

Comment: Thank you for your time. And sorry for not being clear enough. The code works, but when run the addKunder(Kunde customer), the prevously added customer vanishes. The arraylist.size() never goes above one. But the fault is probaly not in the code shown. i will look elsewhere in the code. Again, thanks for your time

Comment: It shouldn't be vanishing if you're re-using the same "dialog", and it just hides/shows that. If you're creating a new dialog each time with FXMLLoader, you'd have a new list, so yes you'd lose the first one. You could also make your "add" method pass a list of customers in, instead of a single object, if the dialog can handle multiple customers. Then you'd only have to call the add method once...

Comment: "If you're creating a new dialog each time with FXMLLoader, you'd have a new list, so yes you'd lose the first one" -- This must be it!, to be honest i dont understand the Parent, loader, scene , and stage code all that much, ive just been using whatever i can find that seems to works. However i dont know what my FXMLLoader should be set to. sounds promising, :)

Comment: i have the code.        
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Parent tableViewParent = loader.load();
        Scene tableViewScene = new Scene(tableViewParent);
      
        //Access the controller and call the method
        FXMLDocumentController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.initForsikredeKunder(valgtKunde); // having trouble finding what it should say instead of = new FXMLLoader();

Comment: @fedoraHacker I added some more detailed suggestions above based on what you added. The new FXMLLoader() bit is fine, that's just a utility class that loads your FXML file when you call fxmlLoader.load().